# ormlite - generate poco files

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I am new to ORMLite. In Entity Framework I can create my POCO files (by using CodeFirst) from an existing database- I read somewhere that this was possible in Ormlite- but I didn't find it within the documentation.

Please recommend a framework to create my poco classes in case ORMLite does not support this feature (I do not want to generate my pocos with EF!)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the T4 templates to generate the POCOs. Have a look at

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/tree/master/src/T4

Comment: These T4 scripts are not working anymore.

Comment: Please create an issue ticket in github and explain what the problem is (and provide the error message) rather than just saying "Not working"

Comment: Hi Guru, first.. thanks for the template, I finally got it to work. To make it work I had to follow the advice from Rob below, I had to remove blank lines at the bottom of `OrmLite.Poco.tt`. I wish I had the error message before I removed those lines.

Comment: Is there some way to make those work in mono?

Answer (score 7):

To get OrmLite.Poco.tt working, remove the blank lines at the end of `OrmLite.Poco.tt` and `OrmLite.Core.ttinclude`.

Comment: Thanks for this.. not sure why though.. but it is working now. tq

Comment: For someone who is new to T4 and get compilation errors, this tip works.